# What do I display until fetch is returned in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a question.
I have a page inside my application that dispatches an action and waits for the result (using useDispatch and useSelector hooks)
I wanted to know what is the right way to display an empty div until I get the results back from the dispatch?
This is what I wrote so far:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchRecommendedPosts } from "../redux/actions/postsActions";
import Post from "../components/sharedComponents/Post";

const RecommendedUserPostsPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { token } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchRecommendedPosts({ token }));
  }, []);

  const fetchedPosts = useSelector((state) => state.posts.recommendedPosts);

  // this is the place where I wait for the response from the dispatch
  const posts =
    fetchedPosts.length > 0 ? (
      fetchedPosts.map((post) => <Post postData={post} />)
    ) : (
      <div />
    );

  return <div style={{ margin: "5em" }}>{posts}</div>;
};

export default RecommendedUserPostsPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always like to add the `data`, `error`, `loading` and `fetched` properties in the Redux state for API data. With these properties, you know exactly what the state is.

These properties needs to be set in your reducers according the API response.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchRecommendedPosts } from "../redux/actions/postsActions";
import Post from "../components/sharedComponents/Post";

const RecommendedUserPostsPage = () => {
  const dispatch  = useDispatch();
  const { token } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  const { data, loading, fetched, error } = useSelector((state) => state.posts.recommendedPosts);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchRecommendedPosts({ token }));
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "5em" }}>
      {fetched && data.map((post) => <Post postData={post} />)}
      {error && <p>Oh no!</p>}
      {loading && <p>Please stay seated...</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RecommendedUserPostsPage;
```

However, more recent there are more people talking about "Avoiding the boolean trap". I haven't used this yet, but I do like the idea.

Instead of having multiple boolean properties which need to be decoded in your container, you only add these properties: `data`, `error` and `state`.

- The `data` property contains your API response data.
- The `error` property will contain the error/problem occurred during the request.
- The `state` property contains an enum (string/number) which represent the current state (obviously) of the request/response.

In your container, you can test the `state` property without having to combine more boolean properties.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchRecommendedPosts } from "../redux/actions/postsActions";
import Post from "../components/sharedComponents/Post";

// this should be in a separate file `./src/enums/RequestState.js`
const RequestState = {
  INITIAL: 'initial',
  FETCHED: 'fetched',
  LOADING: 'loading',
  FAILURE: 'failure',
};

const RecommendedUserPostsPage = () => {
  const dispatch        = useDispatch();
  const { token }       = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { data, state } = useSelector((state) => state.posts.recommendedPosts);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchRecommendedPosts({ token }));
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "5em" }}>
      {state === RequestState.FETCHED && data.map((post) => <Post postData={post} />)}
      {state === RequestState.FAILURE && <p>Oh no!</p>}
      {state === RequestState.LOADING && <p>Please stay seated...</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RecommendedUserPostsPage;
```

Comment: Thanks! last question, why did you change the store property to state.posts.recommendedPosts?

Comment: @Lola, because you are not only interested in the data of the recommendedPost, but also the state and the error that occurred during the request.

Comment: @DennisVash by using code blocks: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: Hehe trust me I know what is code blocks, I meant parsing it like `dispatch         = useDispatch` (with spaces aligned)

Comment: Do you mean why I format it like that? Because I think it's more readable, but that is really opinionated of course. How I do that, in stack overflow by using spaces and by looking at the preview. In my editor, I use ESLint to do this automatically with the varspacing plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-varspacing